# SQL - Check record exists in 2nd table and display the result in main table as separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL - Check record exists in 2nd table and display the result in main table as separate column

I have 2 tables TAB1 and TAB2 as below :

**TAB1**:

```
Sid  Sname  Svalue
===================
1   Joe     22
2   Derk    30
3   Derk1   40
```

**TAB2**:

```
id  name  SID
===================
1   Joe     2
2   Derk    3
```

Result should display as :

```
Sid  Sname  Svalue  Status
============================
1   Joe     22       false
2   Derk    30       true
3   Derk1   40       true
```

Can anyone build the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.Sid,  t1.Sname,  t1.Svalue, CASE WHEN t2.SID IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS Status
FROM Tab1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tab2  t2
   ON t1.SID = t2.SID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
siid,sname,svaluee,
case when b.svalue is null then 'False' else 'true' end as status
 from #t1 t1
outer apply
(
select t2.siid from #t2 t2 where t1.siid=t2.siid) b(svalue)
```

**Output:**

```
siid    sname   svaluee status
1       Joe     22       False
2       Derk    30       true
3       Derk1   40       true
```